# redraw problem after returning from external command

Tags: silent-mode, redraw

When I'm executing an external command in silent mode in vim, when it returns the screen is blank and I need to redraw it.

Here's how I solve it in the `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <F5> :silent :make<CR>:redr!<CR>
```

without the `redr!` the screen is blank and I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>in order to continue.

Is it a bug, or a feature ?

Comment: The design of Vim is _really_ old.  What's going on when you run `:make` is complicated.  On some systems you can fix the flicker, on others you can't.  If your Vim's `shell` is `bash` you might try setting `shellredir` to `&>`.  This works in text mode on most Linux systems (not all), and doesn't work in graphics mode, and on most FreeBSD and OpenBSD systems.

Comment: I wonder how `neovim` approached that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. The `:help :!` (a closely related command) offers this:

```
        Vim redraws the screen after the command is finished,
        because it may have printed any text.  This requires a
        hit-enter prompt, so that you can read any messages.
        To avoid this use:
            :silent !{cmd}
        The screen is not redrawn then, thus you have to use
        CTRL-L or ":redraw!" if the command did display
        something.
```

Comment: Why is it implemented like that?  I don't understand the motive.

Comment: Vim doesn't know whether the command actually did output (only the terminal knows). Doing a redraw just in case would be wasteful (and flicker). So they leave this up to the user (who should know about the command).

Comment: but it doesn't keep the output, the screen is blanked. that's why I ask.

Comment: Right. So a redraw would be necessary, unless you move the cursor, split a window (which redraw implicitly), or issue another external command (and only redraw when done). I'm also only guessing here. I see your point of this not making much sense, but there are several bad defaults (based on its long history) in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31339/silence-specific-message-like-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-correctl) problem myself, and while your own solution worked for me, I believe you could also use [this plugin](https://github.com/fcpg/vim-altscreen).

Here the short description:

```
 This plugin ensures that the output of external commands run in Vim stays in Vim's "virtual screen", and doesn't pollute your main "shell screen".
```